# Is it possible to add LKH package to Julia in version 0.6.4.1?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

To solve a tsp in my codes, I need to use LKH package. But I couldn't add the package to the Julia in 0.6.4.1 version. Unfortunately all my codes in this version.
If you don't mind would you please help me?
Thanks very much.
The following link is for adding LKH package but it doesn't work in before version of Julia.
https://juliapackages.com/p/lkh

Comment: Why are you using Julia 0.6?

Comment: when I started to code, some model of inventory routing problem in mixed integer bi-objective area, the new versions were rarely released and I was new to learn as now I am still new too. Therefore, all codes were written in the version. To improve this model, I have to use this version.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably much easier to upgrade your own code to v1.x, than to "downgrade" someone else's package to 0.6.

The easiest way to update your code is to install v0.7, run your code on that, and then fix all the things you get "deprecation warnings" about.

Version 0.7 was a special version designed to help upgrading to v1.0, and when you run your code on that, you will get warnings/hints about how to fix your code.

If you think this is a hassle, take comfort in the knowledge that your updated code will be runnable for many years. Julia is stable, and v1.x code will not become outdated for a very long time.

This is, imho, better than digging yourself further and further down into a v0.6 hole, which will get increasingly difficult to climb out of.